# Servlet mapping in apache tomcat 6.0.20

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Im not sure that its possible to do what I want to accomplish. I want to map one single servlet to two different URL.

I want both http://10.0.0.1/a and http://10.0.0.1/b to map to the same servlet.

I know its possibe to do the following in web.xml;

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/b</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But that enables the following url: http://10.0.0.1/ContextPath/b/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/a</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/b</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And then both http://host/webapp/a and http://host/webapp/b will be mapped to the same servlet.

If you want to drop the /webapp prefix, you need to set your web app as the ROOT by [setting the path attribtue of the context to "" in your context xml file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common%20Attributes) (under webapps or in META-INF/context.xml)

Comment: you mean the context.xml in <TomcatHome>/conf? (and in <Context> add  <path>""</path> ? )

Comment: I've added the following: <Context path="" />  to server.xml. (Also add the the servlet-mappings mentiond above to the webapp specific web.xml) But i still cant get it to wor properly. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please paste you entire context file? Also, putting it in the server.xml is less prefereable